# Windows Store App - XAML C# - Set ColumnDefinition MaxWidth to Auto programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm sure this must be simple, but I can't spot a way of doing this.

In `XAML` you would do it like this

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I have dynamic content that constantly changes, so I have no idea how many row's and column's I will need. So I need to programmatically populate my `Grid` something like this.

```
int column = 0;
for(UIElements uie in myElemnts)
{
    ColumnDefinition def = new ColumnDefinition();
    def.Width = AUTO; // How do I represent Auto here?
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(column, def);
    Grid.SetColumn(uie, column++);
    myGrid.Children.Add(uie);

}
```

What how is `Auto` value represented?

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

```
def.Width = GridLength.Auto;
```